# Wrong jira home path on linux

Tags: linux, installation, jira

I used the jira archive, unzipped, configured and run it on a linux machine.
The tomcat starts, I can access the webapp at port 8080, but it shows me the following error in the browser:

```
Your current jira.home is: "/media/storage/jira_home" which is not absolute.
Review our documentation for more information on setting your JIRA home.
```

I checked just to be sure, and that path looks as an absolute path to me.
I also tried with other paths like `~/jira` or so, but with no success.
Could someone tell me what may cause this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the jira.home configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to install jira to /opt/atlassian/jira

Use /media only for mounting file systems